# Firefox doesn’t know how to open this address, because of protocols (unsafe)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I generated magnetic links in my ionic app

```
generateMagneticLink(hash:any,title:any){
let magneticLinkgeneraal:any='magnet:?xt=urn:btih:'+hash+'&dn='+title+ 
'&tr=http://track.one:1234/announce&tr=udp://track.two:80'
'&tr=udp://glotorrents.pw:6969/announce&tr';
 this.trackerHashcode.push(magneticLinkgeneraal);
}
```

and my template to access the links is

```
<ion-row nowrap>
<ion-col *ngFor='let s of trackerHashcode'>
  <a href="{{s}}">
     <ion-icon name='magnet' item-start></ion-icon>
  </a>
 </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

when i clck on the links in my app the browser add the unsafe protocol and doesn't open the magnetic link but if i manually delete the unsafe protocol it opens the link with my utorrent app, n downloads the torrent,
Anyone with the idea on how to prevent the unsafe protocol from appearing

Comment: This isn't an Angular issue, I think this is just a Firefox issue => https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1012864

Comment: that may work on my browser but , if someone else  uses the app on a different machine will also have to do the same configuration which is not productive, i thought os the sanitization thing i cant go around it

Comment: and that doesnt solve the problem,

Comment: I'm thinking this isn't really a sanitization issue or anything like that. I'm saying it's a Firefox configuration thing, not anything to do with Angular.